# How to access the body from a component

Tags: angular

I have an angular app in which I have that property coming from 'body' tag `overflow-y: auto`. The problem is, I want to set `overflow-y: hidden` just for one single page. In order to do that I have to access the body tag from a component. That's my problem, I just can't do that.

I've tried

```
:host >>> body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```
:host(body) {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And none of these worked.

In that live example I can't change for example the body background from `hero-details-box.css`

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kmqqeakjvya

Comment: Can you provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? https://stackblitz.com/ is great for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` for your component, which would allow to set the body style directly:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ExampleComponent { }
```

---

Or you can use deep selectors. They are marked as deprecated but still they do work in the latest Angular 8.2.4:

```css
/deep/ body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* or */

>>> body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* or */

::ng-deep body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

---

But be **careful** with both of these methods, as they are **highly bug-prone**. The component styles are designed to work on the element itself. Because styles are applied without element selector, it could **interfere with the website** even when the component was destroyed.

The better way to do something like this, is to **communicate with you main component** (or `<body>` directive) using services and **apply your styles there**. This would require you to change quite a bit of the application, but it is more **safer and cleaner** approach.

Comment: Don't use deep selectors, they're deprecated. Don't  switch off ViewEncapsulation unless you want your styles to bleed into all other components. This will also effect your final bundle size as it makes tree-shaking less effective.

Comment: @AndrewHill Ok, but so far it's an approach that worked

Comment: @FelipeEndlich it all depends how strict you are about doing things the right way. If you want something that just works - go for it. If you want to do things by the book, I'd suggest a different solution - this one is hacky at best.

Comment: @AndrewHill That's exactly what I have wrote at the end. Sometimes you just need to make it work, even if  it's not the appropriate way.

Comment: @Krypt1 Actually AndrewHill is not that wrong, we all have tight deadlines, so right now I'll just leave a mark in my code, and try to solve it later, but unfortunately real world sometimes force us to do things that are not ideal

Comment: @AndrewHill Well we don't really know what kind of project is this. Maybe it's a weekend project, proof of concept, startup or a student assignment. It could as well be an emergency fix, which is required right here and right now. Assumptions might be even more dangerous than technical debt in software development. Anyway, I did write a note why I do not encourage this solution and how I think is a better way to solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

> Refer [angular component styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Angular applications are styled with standard CSS. That means you can apply everything you know about CSS stylesheets, selectors, rules, and media queries directly to Angular applications.

Additionally, Angular can bundle component styles with components, enabling a more modular design than regular stylesheets.

This page describes how to load and apply these component styles.

You can run the live [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kmqqeakjvya) in Stackblitz to experience how to put styles inside component

edit(As your requirement try the following method):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <style>
      body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  `
})
```

Comment: edited there are various methords. you should take a look and try most suitable methord for you

Comment: That's what I'm trying to explain, with that method that you've showed I can edit the ```host```, but not exactly the body tag, which I'm trying to achieve. In that live example, try to edit the ```hero-details-box.css``` and change the body background.

Comment: Also not working with ```styles: ['body { overflow-y: hidden; }']```

Answer (score 0):

The point of an encapsulated component system is to prevent you from placing code not related to the component outside of the component. The correct way to handle this would be on your top level `app.component` where any other modifications to the `<body>` might occur.

You should check your current route and apply a CSS class accordingly since the `<body>` is not a part of your component.

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.router.url === '/overflow-hidden-url') {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'hide-overflow');
    }
  }
}
```

You can then select this HTML class in your global stylesheet for the body (again, this isn't component specific, it's a direct edit of the body).

```
body {
  overflow-y: auto

  &.hide-overflow {
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```